# I'm not able to add SQL file to postgresql database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I started with basics and did these steps:

- `createdb -U postgres -E UTF8 -O Peete gis` -OK
- `createlang -U postgres plpgsql gis` (was already installed) -OK
- `psql -U postgres -d gis -f PATH_TO_POSTGRES/share/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql` -OK
- `psql -U postgres -d gis -f PATH_TO_FILE/4326.sql` (I downloaded file from [Spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/) and chose "PostGIS spatial_ref_sys INSERT statement") - OK
- Then I ran this command `shp2pgsql -c -s 4326 -I roads.shp > roads.sql`-OK
- Now I wanted to add this SQL file to my database created above so I ran this command: `psql -d gis -f roads.sql`-FAILED

I got this error message:

```
ERROR:  AddGeometryColumn() - invalid SRID

CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7)"

PL/pgSQL function addgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer,character varying,integer,boolean) line 5 at SQL statement
********** Error **********
```

The shapefile I'm using is in WGS84 coordinate system `EPSG:4326`

Any recommendations?

Comment: check what line 5 in your roads.sql file says, which SRID is it trying to use

Comment: @bugmenot123 In line 5 the roads.sql file says this: `"objectid" int4,`

Comment: Verify you do have sird 4326 in your spatial_ref_sys table.  I presume you do since you loaded, but who knows.

Comment: @LR1234567 Yes, i did. Actually don't know where problem can be in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do some changes and this looks like solution since everything works.

I deleted old database and again created new one by creating a spatial database directly in pgAdmin:

- Created new database (name,owner...)
- Opened the query dialog box and wrote

> CREATE EXTENSION postgis; 
>   and then SELECT postgis_full_version();

This step probably added all coordinate systems to database.After this inside the public schema, you will see one PostGIS-specific metadata table, spatial_ref_sys.

Then i again ran

> shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 PATH_TO\roads.shp roads | psql -U postgres -d MyDatabase

Done.